# issue with expect exception handling in foreach loop

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I have a expect script that fires commands on remote devices, some of the devices can have credentials issues for which I need to skip is the password prompt repeats after entering the password.

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect -f
    
    set x [list 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2]
    
    foreach hosts $x {
    # spawn ssh sy-nep-oss@$x
    sleep 5
    spawn ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  sy-nep-oss@$hosts
    sleep 5
   
    **expect {"password: "
    send -- "abcd\r"
   
    expect "*>"
```

If the password is incorrect, need to skip this loop iteration and move on to the next item in the list

```
    send -- "cd cfcard:/ \r"
    sleep 2
    expect "*>"
    send -- "cd cfcard2:/ \r"
    sleep 2
    expect "*>"
    sleep 2
    send -- "dir log* \r"
    expect "*>"
    sleep 2
    send "cd log \r"
    expect {enter code here
      "Error: Wrong path *" {
        send "cd logfile \r"
      }
      "logfile*" {
        send "cd log \r"
      }
    }
    expect "*>"
    sleep 2
    send -- "dir log.log \r"
    expect "*>"
    sleep 2
    send -- "system-view \r"
    expect "Enter system view*"
    sleep 2
    send -- "sftp 212.72.10.182 \r"
    expect  "*username*"
    sleep 2
    send -- "test\r"
    expect  "*password:"
    sleep 2
    send -- "Y\r"
    sleep 3
    send -- "N \r"
    sleep 4
    expect "Please select public key type for user authentication*"
    send -- "R \r"
    sleep 2
    expect  "*password"
    sleep 2
    expect "sftp-client>"
    sleep 2
    send -- "put log.log $hosts.log \r "
    sleep 2
    expect "sftp-client>"
    sleep 2
    send -- "quit\r"
    sleep 2
    send -- "quit\r"
    sleep 2
    send -- "quit\r"
    }
    expect eof
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: the requirement is if the password login fails , ie is the prompt for passwrd repeats i need to skill the following commands and move on to the next item in the array

Comment: Tcl also has a [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm) statement.

Comment: When you say "skill" do you perhaps mean "skip" ?

Comment: yes sorry about the typo, skipping the faulting IP address, for example, you have a device on which you do not have permissions so you move on to the next!